# Why won't my Monk Trainer teach me new skills?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I started playing a monk and as I played I gained new spells on the way, at some point I got my first spell that I did not automatically learn and it said `See your Trainer`, but when visiting my trainer I do not have the option to learn any spells, how do I learn the missing skill?

[image: Monk Trainer]

Comment: This bug occurred in WoW beta only - never in live.  Also - trainers no longer teach skills as of Patch 5.0.4, so no player can get into the situation described by the question.  As such - question should be deleted.

Comment: @DavidB monks are not in live yet so your comment is invalid.

Comment: I think you missed the point of @David's comment.

Comment: 5.0.4 has removed "trainers teach skills".  Skills are now learned automatically.

Comment: This is a bug that existed while the "trainers teach skills" was removed. You can not say it never existed in live since no one has played a monk in live yet. and based on [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5282/can-we-stop-closing-questions-that-have-become-obsolete-as-too-localized) meta post questions like this should not be closed as too localized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug, although it appears you're [not the only one encountering it](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/6307651500).

Looking at your screenshot, I gather you are below level 14 (since Provoke is greyed out).  Chi Torpedo is a level 90 talent, so shouldn't be available at that level and shouldn't be off a trainer anyway.  [Check out Blizzard's Monk talent trees for confirmation](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/game/mists-of-pandaria/feature/talent-specification#f!).